# Forwarding json response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a simple html file. It access url1 and successfully parse the json response.

CLIENT  -> URL1 -> Response to client

I modified my code in html and invoked URL2

CLIENT -> URL2 -> URL1 -> Response to URL2 -> Response to Client

I commented url1 and invoked url2. url2 is a simple servlet which invokes url1 and gets the response. The servlets returns the same response back to the client but this time ajax/jquery returns **parse error**. When i alert (request.responseText), it exactly matches the response returned by URL1.

```
$.ajax({   
//url: "http://abc1.com", // Line 1  
  url: "http://abc2.com", // Line 2   
  data: {param1, param2},    
  dataType: "jsonp",            
  type: "GET",  
      async:false,  
    success: function(parsed_json) {  
            alert("Success");           
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {  
            alert("Error" + error);
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
```

The Servlet is just a layer in between which copies the content of the input stream to the output stream.

`InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();

resp.setContentType("application/json");
// Apache commons IOUtils to copy 
IOUtils.copy(input, resp.getOutputStream());

resp.getOutputStream().flush();`

I manually verified the json-string-response and it appears to be the same. 
What could be the problem ?

Comment: Could you please include an example json string. (Shortened if it's a big sample)

Comment: @Mithon The json string is big but after reading your comment i feel i should try with smaller json string to find out the problem.

Comment: Here's a usefull linkey for you: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Mithon i did verify the json response string and it is valid. In the error block the The error says the query was not called. If i print status it says parse error. The request.responseText is valid Json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible issue: I note that `dataType` is `jsonp`, which is different than `json`. jQuery could conceivably throw an error if the request came back as JSON when it was expecting JSON-P. Does changing the `dataType` to `json` change anything?

Here's the difference, by the way:

JSON-P is used primarily for communicating with remote websites. Since browsers can't send AJAX requests to other domains for security reasons, a JSON-P "AJAX request" will actually add something like this to the DOM:

```
<script src="http://www.otherwebsite.com/info.js?callback=myCallback"></script>
```

If the remote site supports JSON-P, it will return something like this:

```
myCallback({"foo": "bar"})
```

Then your `myCallback` function is called with the data from the remote site - ta da!

jQuery handles all this callback business automatically if you say `dataType` is `jsonp`, but, if you say `jsonp` but *don't* wrap the data in a callback, (as I understand it) jQuery will notice that the script loaded and throw an error since the callback never fired.

Or maybe it *is* JSON-P and I'm just wasting by breath. Anyway. Just in case :)

Comment: He's attempting to do cross domain scripting, which is why he needs jsonp. I'm quite confident js2 is doing that on purpose.

Comment: @Mithon: meh. Question was ambiguous, so, since he had access to URL2's source code, I assumed it was on his domain. Just a shot in the dark, really (:

Comment: @Matchu I ignored data-type for such a long time. You didn't wasted your time. Your answer really helped. Thanks. The URL1 is not in my domain and supports jsonp, whereas when i wrote url2 i was returning json data type and not jsonp. Thanks Mithon 2.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for this, and it appears that "Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation". So if you change to `async:true`, you might have some more luck. :)